# Hover state remains until something else is hovered

Tags: jquery, hover, tooltip

I want to create a hover tooltip which displays what's inside the span and stays until something another element is hovered over.

HTML

```
       <div class="man">
         <div class="parts">
           <div class="cc-head"><a href="#"><span>Text Head</span></a></div>
           <div class="cc-neck"><a href="#"><span>Text Neck</span></a></div>   
         </div>
       </div>
```

This is the Jquery I have so far,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.parts div a').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).addClass('showinfo');
   });
});
```

It's set to display:none as default and when that class gets added it's display:block. The part I need help on is having the class remain even on mouseout + until something else is mouseover-ed.

Many thanks, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything? or maybe searched SO before asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333546/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-message-on-hover-using-jquery

Comment: try to trigger your tooltip with .mouseover() and .mouseout() to remove/hide the tooltip http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: I've got as far as adding a class on hover. My Jquery is very very basic and I dont understand how to adjust the code from other threads to work for me. 
 $('.parts a span').mouseover(function() {
     $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `mouseover` select (if existing) element with `showinfo`-class and remove the class.

After that, apply `showinfo`to your hovered element. Should be no problem for you.

This way, the class will remain on that element until some other element gets hovered.

Implementation:

> ```
>   $('.parts div a').mouseover(function() {
>        // remove Class if there is an element with class already applied
>        $('.showinfo').removeClass('showinfo');
>        // Apply your class to this
>        $(this).addClass('showinfo');
>     });
> ```

Comment: That's no problem, i edit my answer to give you some implementation hints.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to write that but it's not removing the showinfo class of previous elements when it's added to another.

Comment: It does, I just missed the `.` in the selector. You could have caught that :-p Note: copy&pasting doesn't improve programming skill.

Comment: Many thanks, I am trying to learn JQuery but am a at a less than basic level atm.

Comment: No problem. I didn't want to be offending, sry if this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

After reffering the answer posted by 'psychotik',
[How can I display a tooltip message on hover using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333546/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-message-on-hover-using-jquery)

I think the below solution should suffice your needs. Hope it helps you.

Solution:

**Jquery Script :**

```
       $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".cc-head").hover(function(){
                $(this).attr('title',$(this).children().children().html());
            });

       });
```

**html :**

```
 <div class="man">
         <div class="parts">
           <div class="cc-head"><a href="#"><span>Text Head</span></a></div>
           <div class="cc-head"><a href="#"><span>Text Neck</span></a></div>   
         </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Does this need a 'title' element to be used in the html?

Comment: no. there is no need to add a title element in html. The .attr() adds the 'title' attribute to the div on which you hover. Did you try the above code?

Answer (score 0):

With the below solution, i hope your problem is solved..

```
<html>

  <head>

    <style type="text/css">

        .tooltip 
        {
            position:absolute;

            border:1px solid gray;
            border-radius: 3px;

            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            padding:5px;

            color:white;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

    </style>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" >

       $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".cc-head").hover(function(){

                var tooltip_text = $(this).children().children().html(); //contains the data present inside 'span' element

                $('<p class="tooltip"></p>').html(tooltip_text).appendTo('body').fadeIn('slow'); //showing the tooltip

            }, function() { // remove the tooltip as soon as it goes outside the div

                $('.tooltip').remove();

            }).mousemove(function(e) {

                var x_pos = e.pageX + 15; //calculating the position of tooltip from x-axis, pageX gives the current position of mouse pointer from x-axis
                var y_pos = e.pageY + 10; //calculating the position of tooltip from y-axis, pageY gives the current position of mouse pointer from y-axis

                // assigning the css to .tooltip
                $('.tooltip').css('left',x_pos);
                $('.tooltip').css('top',y_pos); 

        });

       });

  </script>

 </head>

 <body>

   <div class="man">

         <div class="parts">

           <div class="cc-head"><a href="#"><span>Text Head</span></a></div>
           <div class="cc-head"><a href="#"><span>Text Neck</span></a></div> 

         </div>
   </div>

 </body>

</html>
```